# Wordfile for CMake syntax highlighting in UltraEdit?

Tags: ultraedit

Does there exist a wordfile for CMake syntax highlighting in UltraEdit?

I found [this wiki page](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/Editors) but the link to the wordfile is broken. So I know it has existed in the past, but where do I find it now?

Comment: It looks like the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910055648/http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/images/5/56/UltraEditWordfile.tar.gz) has a copy from 2015.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Thanks, that works for me.

Comment: Glad it helped. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it looks as if the original link provided by the [wiki page in your original question](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/Editors) references a file (i.e. `UltraEditWordfile.tar.gz`) that no longer exists, there is a copy of that file available on the [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/2015*/https://cmake.org/Wiki/images/5/56/UltraEditWordfile.tar.gz) from 2015, with a [direct download link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910055648/http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/images/5/56/UltraEditWordfile.tar.gz) available.